# Update Secondary DB table using Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have two azure sql databases - Master and Secondary. Both contains same table. For ex. Product table. When I insert into or update Product table from Master DB, Product table from Secondary DB should get updated using Logic App.

Answer (score 1):

We built [data sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync) for this purpose. Check it out!

You could also use two connections and submit to both databases if, for some reason, Data Sync didn't meet your needs.

Comment: Yes It is good option. But why it's in preview since long time?

Comment: I can't speak to that, but Josh wrote [briefly of the intent to bring it to GA in February](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-data-sync-update/)